# Stateful LSTM with Embedding Layer (shapes don't match)

Tags: keras, lstm, keras-layer

I am trying to build a stateful LSTM with Keras and I don't understand how to add a embedding layer before the LSTM runs. The problem seems to be the `stateful` flag. If my net is not stateful adding the embedding layer is quite straight forward and works.

A working stateful LSTM without embedding layer looks at the moment like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(EMBEDDING_DIM,
               batch_input_shape=(batchSize, longest_sequence, 1),
               return_sequences=True,
               stateful=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(maximal_value)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(...)
```

When adding the Embedding layer I move the `batch_input_shape` parameter into the Embedding layer i.e. only the first layer needs to known the shape? 
Like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocabSize+1, EMBEDDING_DIM,batch_input_shape=(batchSize, longest_sequence, 1),))
model.add(LSTM(EMBEDDING_DIM,
               return_sequences=True,
               stateful=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(maximal_value)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(...)
```

The exception I get know is `Exception: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4`

So I am stuck here at the moment. What is the trick to combine word embeddings into a stateful LSTM?

Answer (score 5):

The batch_input_shape parameter of the Embedding layer should be *(batch_size, time_steps)*, where time_steps is the length of the unrolled LSTM / number of cells and batch_size is the number of examples in a batch.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(
   input_dim=input_dim, # e.g, 10 if you have 10 words in your vocabulary
   output_dim=embedding_size, # size of the embedded vectors
   input_length=time_steps,
   batch_input_shape=(batch_size,time_steps)
))
model.add(LSTM(
   10, 
   batch_input_shape=(batch_size,time_steps,embedding_size),
   return_sequences=False, 
   stateful=True)
)
```

There is an excellent [blog post](http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/) which explains stateful LSTMs in Keras. Also, I've uploaded a [gist](https://gist.github.com/stefanthaler/017370e1cb8c21a22b36db3fa625c99f) which contains a simple example of a stateful LSTM with Embedding layer.

Comment: How do you decide the embedding_size or find out the size of the embedded vectors?

Comment: @naisanza The embedding_size is a hyper parameter. This means that the embedding_size depends on your problem, and you are free to choose it.

Unfortunately, I cannot really give you a general answer on how to choose good hyperparameters, but https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.5533.pdf provides a good start on that topic.